# Sliding Effect Button/Div/radio Button

Tags: html, jquery, css

I would like to slide the orange background color to 100 (left to right) when i select 100, 
and slide back to 50 (right to left) when i select 50. 
I am doing this effect on **radio button** but could achieved. I know there's alot of similar questions over internet but i couldnt find  solution for my case.

I do also tried with keyframe but not working. What i want is the background color to change to another radio button everytime checked on it. 
 It's not just applying the color code on it. but also sliding effect. 
Thanks for help. This image is what i need to achieve
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VezZ7.png)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49440076/8620333

Comment: Share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.btnDiv{
   background:transparent;
   height:30px;
   width:100px;
   border:1px solid #ddd;
   color:white;
   display: inline-block;
   position:relative;
}
*{margin:0;}
.selected{
   background:orange;
   height:30px;
   width:100px;
}
.right-to-left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  animation: myfirst 5s 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
  100%  {background: yellow; left: 100px; top: 0px;}
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<div style="background:green;width:203px;height:30px;display:block;position:relative;margin:auto;">
<div id="btn50" class="btnDiv" selected="1" onclick="MoveSelected('btn50','btn100')" style="z-index:1;">
   <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2;text-align:center;width:100%;margin-top:5px;">50</div>
   <div id="movablediv" class="selected" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;"></div>
</div>
<div id="btn100" class="btnDiv" selected="0" onclick="MoveSelected('btn100','btn50')" style="z-index:2;margin-left:-6px;">
   <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2;text-align:center;width:100%;margin-top:5px;">100</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
   
   function MoveSelected(value1,value2)
   {
  
   var val = document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute("selected");
   if(val == "0")
   {
       document.getElementById(value1).setAttribute("selected", "1");
          document.getElementById(value2).setAttribute("selected", "0");
          getMove('movablediv');
   }
         
   }
  var pos = 0;
  function getMove(value) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(value);   
  
  if(pos <= 0)
  {
      var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (pos > 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
  }
  else
  {
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (0 >= pos) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
  }
 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.content-wrapper
{
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.radio_wrap {
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:0;
 --i:0;
}
.radio_wrap:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  top:1px;
  left:calc( var(--i) * (100% / 2));
  height:30px;
  background:orange;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
}

label {
  min-width: calc(100% / 2);
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #dfe0e4;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  height:30px;
  padding-top:5px;
}

input:checked+label {
  color: white;
}
.template-wrapper
{
   width:200px;
   height:30px;
   margin:auto;
   background:green;
}
#byBtn{
   width:150px;
   height:35px;
   background:#333;
   border:1px solid #ddd;
   margin:10px;
   color:white;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="template-wrapper">
     
  <div class="radio_wrap">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio1" name="radiogroup" checked="on">
  <label for="radio1" data-i="0">50</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio2" name="radiogroup">
  <label for="radio2" data-i="1">100</label>
</div>
   </div>
  <button id="byBtn">GetValue</button>
     
</div>
<script>
  $('label').click(function() {
   $('.radio_wrap').attr('style','--i:'+$(this).data('i'));
});
 $('#byBtn').click(function() {
     var rd50 = $("input[id='radio1']:checked").val();
     var rd100 = $("input[id='radio2']:checked").val();
          alert("radio1 value : " + rd50 + "--  radio2 value : " + rd100);
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```